# SonarQube msbuild runner does not import all fxcop messages

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We use sonarqube and the sonarqube msbuild runner in our TFS vNext builds. The integration works: we see new analysis results in sonarqube as expected. However, not all issues from the CodeAnalysisLog.xml are imported in sonarqube. If we run the analysis locally, those issues are reported. If we inspect the CodeAnalysisLog.xml as produced on the build server, the issue is present in the file. SonarQube however does not show it. We do use custom rule-sets, but everything is configured correctly locally and on the server.

I tried to look at the source code to see how the parsing and filtering works, but cannot find anything. I've looked at the open issues on Jira, but see nothing that looks related.

How can I debug this further? And are other experiencing the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be fixed with the upcoming SonarQube C# plugin version 5.2, whose RC1 is currently available for testing: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/0gghnIQf3XU

Comment: The issue was mostly fixed, but we still have issues that are not imported. Are there any known issues?